# How to get all external image in wp post

Tags: php, wordpress

I did not use attachment to upload image in wp post,
I use external host like dropbox, how to get it to my frontpage by specific post-type ?

example

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/drgdrfhdtj.jpg?raw=1" alt="" width="506" height="673" />

<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/djtfdtjdtmjx.jpg?raw=1" alt="" width="506" height="714" />
```

how to get all this image ?

my code in function.php

```
function gallery (){ 

    $pid = get_the_ID();

$post = get_post( $pid );
$content = $post->post_content;
$regex = '/src="([^"]*)"/';
preg_match_all( $regex, $content, $matches );
foreach($matches as $image):

   echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$post->post_title.'" title="'.$post->post_title.'">' ;

endforeach;
}
```

my code in content-gallery.php

```
<?php $post_format = get_post_format(); ?>

        <?php if ( $post_format == 'gallery' ) : ?>

            <div class="featured-media">    


                <?php gallery(); ?>
            </div> <!-- /featured-media -->


        <?php endif; ?>
```

but this do not work

edit:

work used image[1] (@master djon answer)

now problem is

output:

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/image1.jpg""><img https://www.dropbox.com/s/image1.jpg">
```

double output one image `<img src=` and `<img https://`

how fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`$image` is an array of all groups contained in found match. Index zero is the whole matching (`src="URL"`), and index 1 is what you search for : the URL.

So you shall you `$image[1]` instead of `$image`.

Comment: this output : <img src="Array" alt="" title=""><img src="Array" alt="" title=""></div>

Comment: You mean : using `$image` in `src=$image` or by using `"src=" . $image[1]` ? That gives you `src="Array"`

Comment: oh yeah, work , image get only 1, i have 10 image , how to display it all automatic ? without image[2], image[3]....

Comment: You set each match from `$matches` to `$image`, so each match shall be in `$image`. So, all iteration showing the URL is from `$image[1]`.

Comment: In "my code in function.php" you should use `$image[1]` instead of `$image`

Comment: already change it echo'<img src="'.$image[1].'" alt="'.$post->post_title.'" title="'.$post->post_title.'">' ; but work only one image , can't multiple

Comment: why output is double <img src= and <img https:// . i have edit my question. thank you

Comment: Can you update the code in your question ? (Because at least I don't see `$image[1]`)